# python jsonschema - get the reason of validation failure

Tags: python, jsonschema

I have a json file which I need to compare with official F5 schema. Everything works but when I do any mistake it does not show me a path or an error, it just shows me that its valid under any of the given schemas.

My json file:

```json
{
   "schema": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/F5Networks/f5-appsvcs-extension/master/schema/latest/as3-schema.json",
   "class": "AS3",
   "action": "deploy",
   "persist": true,
   "declaration": {
       "class": "ADC",
       "schemaVersion": "3.40.0",
       "target": {
           "hostname": "test.test.com"
       },
       "id": "version_21.0",
       "label": "211008",
       "remark": "CO_version_21.0"
   }
}
```

Here is the Python script:

```py
import json
import requests
from jsonschema import Draft7Validator, ValidationError

def load_json_from_url(url):
   response = requests.get(url)
   return response.json()


def main():
   schema_url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/F5Networks/f5-appsvcs-extension/master/schema/latest/as3-schema.json'
   schema = load_json_from_url(schema_url)
  
   schema['$id'] = schema['$id'].replace('urn:uuid:', '')

   with open('gtm1.json', 'r') as f:
       validJson = json.load(f)

   validator = Draft7Validator(schema)

   try:
       validator.validate(validJson)
       print('The JSON file is valid according to the schema.')
   except ValidationError as e:
       message = e.schema["error_msg"] if "error_msg" in e.schema else e.message
       print(f'Invalid data: {message}')

if __name__ == '__main__':
   main()
```

If I were to change the json example from

```json
{
    ...
    "declaration": {
        "class": "ADC",
        ...
    }
}
```

To:

```json
{
    ...
    "declaration": {
        "class": "ADC1",
        ...
    }
}
```

Inside the script I have tried

```py
message = e.schema["error_msg"] if "error_msg" in e.schema else e.message
```

`e.path` or `e.json_path` but nothing works

Here is the output:

`Invalid data: {'schema': 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/F5Networks/f5-appsvcs-extension/master/schema/latest/as3-schema.json', 'class': 'AS3', 'action': 'deploy', 'persist': True, 'declaration': {'class': 'ADC1', 'schemaVersion': '3.40.0', 'target': {'hostname': 'test.test.com'}, 'id': 'version_21.0', 'label': '211008', 'remark': 'CO_version_21.0'}} is not valid under any of the given schemas`

How can I get the path to an item that caused validation to fail? I'd like to obtain something like `.declaration.class`, because this item is the invalid one (this specific output format is not important, e.g. list of path components would be also fine).

Comment: you mean changing to "ADC1" or just ADC1? cos json will not recognize what ADC1 is. Also please post the full stack trace

Comment: added output I need to just change value so "class": "ADC1"

Comment: of course it will fail the validation since there's no ADC1 in the f5 url

Comment: @Kulasangar as far as I understand, the question is not "why does it fail", OP introduces the changes to examine script behavior with invalid input data. The question is: how to get the JSON path(s) to invalid item(s), when validation fails? I'd say that this is impossible, because json schema may have a meet type for some item, and so you need an error against every meet item (which may be a nested schema as well), and such output can grow exponentially and quickly become unusable.

Answer (score 0):

problem solved

from jsonschema import Draft7Validator  does not work
I used from jsonschema import validate